# Array.find and Array.findIndex has worst performance in LWC Lightning Locker

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

For the component chain like below:

```
<container>
    <parent>
        <child>
            <grand-child>
```

Pass an Array from `container` to all the way down to `grand-child`. This is how we should communicate down the hierarchy according to LWC best practices. When we use any [array function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), the performance is excellent when used in `parent` but is worst and adversely affected when in `grand-child` and worst of all the functions affected are [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

Consider the example in this [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/ZapdM4Ph/3/edit) - **This will work fine in playground as locker service is disabled but when you test in any dev org/sandbox, you will notice the difference**

1. Click on `Load` to load array
2. Click on test buttons to check performance in parent, child and grand-child.

Below are the results:

[image]

I found the solution by using JSON.parse and JSON.stringify or else if its only single level array objects then by using shallow copy by [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). However, we are not supposed to implement our own work-around and so considering this as bug in LWC.

**Why are all array functions multi-fold affected with each passing level? And why specially find and findIndex are affected much worse?
Is this known issue? If so, is there a fix for this in road-map?**

---

Copying the playground example here as they will be deleted:

app.html:

```html
<template>
    <lightning-button label="Load" onclick={load}>
    </lightning-button>
    <lightning-button label="Test Main" onclick={test}>
    </lightning-button>

    <c-performance-child1 myarray={myarray}></c-performance-child1>
</template>
```

app.js:

```js
import PerformanceInherit from 'c/performanceInherit';

export default class App extends PerformanceInherit { }
```

performanceInherit.js:

```js
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class PerformanceInherit extends LightningElement {
    compId = 'parent';

    @api myarray = [];

    load() {
        let myarray = [];
        for (let i = 1; i < 111; i++) {
            myarray.push('elem ' + i);
        }
        this.myarray = myarray;
    }

    test() {
        let t1 = new Date().getTime();
        this.myarray.find(item => false);
        let t2 = new Date().getTime();
        console.log('find ______', this.compId + ' => ', (t2 - t1) + ' ms');

        let t3 = new Date().getTime();
        this.myarray.forEach(item => item);
        let t4 = new Date().getTime();
        console.log('forEach ___', this.compId + ' => ', (t4 - t3) + ' ms');

        let t5 = new Date().getTime();
        this.myarray.filter(item => false);
        let t6 = new Date().getTime();
        console.log('filter ____', this.compId + ' => ', (t6 - t5) + ' ms');

        let t7 = new Date().getTime();
        this.myarray.map(item => item);
        let t8 = new Date().getTime();
        console.log('map _______', this.compId + ' => ', (t8 - t7) + ' ms');

        let t9 = new Date().getTime();
        this.myarray.findIndex(item => false);
        let t10 = new Date().getTime();
        console.log('findIndex _', this.compId + ' => ', (t10 - t9) + ' ms');

        console.log('_________________', this.myarray.length);
    }
}
```

performanceChild1.html

```html
<template>
    <lightning-button label="Test Parent"
                      onclick={test}>
    </lightning-button>

    <c-performance-child2 myarray={myarray}></c-performance-child2>
</template>
```

performanceChild1.js

```js
import PerformanceInherit from 'c/performanceInherit';

export default class PerformanceChild1 extends PerformanceInherit { }
```

performanceChild2.html

```html
<template>
    <lightning-button label="Test Child"
                      onclick={test}>
    </lightning-button>

    <c-performance-child3 myarray={myarray}></c-performance-child3>
</template>
```

performanceChild2.js

```js
import PerformanceInherit from 'c/performanceInherit';

export default class PerformanceChild2 extends PerformanceInherit {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.compId = 'child';
    }
}
```

performanceChild3.html

```html
<template>
    <lightning-button label="Test Grand-Child"
                      onclick={test}>
    </lightning-button>
</template>
```

performanceChild3.js

```js
import PerformanceInherit from 'c/performanceInherit';

export default class PerformanceChild3 extends PerformanceInherit {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.compId = 'grand-child';
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect it is more to do with proxies than the locker service directly. Every API and tracked property value gets proxified to ensure reactive handling and I suspect this happens even when the value is already a proxy (so access to the underlying value becomes more and more nested - I am speculating here). Perhaps this is compounded by some aspect of the locker service?

Comment: @PhilW, Yes! this is what I too suspected and so put locker service in question heading directly.

Comment: it might be a good idea to copy out the playground example into the question before Salesforce [kills stored playground examples](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/314110/lwc-playground-save-option-removed).

Answer (score 14):

It due to LockerService overriding the getters on Arrays when it's wrapped in a Proxy.  There is a function called `getFilteredArray(st, raw, key)` which is called every time you try to access a property on an array.  Here is the source code for it:

```
function getFilteredArray(st, raw, key) {
    const filtered = [];
    // TODO: RJ, we are missing named(non-integer) properties, changing this for loop to for..in should fix it
    for (let n = 0; n < raw.length; n++) {
      const value = raw[n];
      let validEntry = false;
      if (
        !value || // Array can contain undefined/null/false/0 such falsy values
        getKey(value) === key // Value has been keyed and belongs to this locker
      ) {
        validEntry = true;
      } else {
        const filteredValue = filterEverything(st, value, { defaultKey: key });
        if (filteredValue && !isOpaque(filteredValue)) {
          validEntry = true;
        }
      }
      if (validEntry) {
        // Store the raw index and value in an object
        filtered.push({ rawIndex: n, rawValue: value });
      }
    }

    return filtered;
  }
```

This function loops through your entire array every time you try to access an element in your array.  So if you loop through your array a certain way (e.g. `for(...)` then what you expect to be an O(n) operation, actually becomes a O(n^2) operation.

You can see the rest of the Proxy handler if you look for the `aura_proddebug.js` file and look for `function getArrayProxyHandler(key)`.  You will need to have debug mode on for you user.

Comment: Seems that @salesforce-sas is right and this should be considered a bug; at the very least it is poor programming in the Lightning infrastructure.