# Loop in javascript setter takes 1 second per iteration

Tags: lightning-web-components, setter, js

I have an array attribute in my LWC component which is set from the parent LWC. I have some logic that runs when the this attribute is set. I have used getter and setter for this. My array is a wrapper that has 3 attributes in it. There is a for loop in the setter that iterates over the array. When the size of the array is large say around 500, this loop processes very very slow. It takes a second per iteration or even more. This works perfectly fine when the array size is small. Even JSON.stringify(arr) takes 5 - 6 minutes if the array size is large. I tried to iterate the array in the parent component and it works fine there. I am not able to figure out what might be wrong.

```
@api
get optionsFromParent(){
    return this.options;
}
set optionsFromParent(opt){
    console.log('options are'+JSON.stringify(opt));
    for(let i=0;i<opt.length;i++){
           //do something here
    }
    this.options = opt;
}
```

Comment: if you add a `console.log` inside the loop, do you continuously see it being logged? Or does it start logging and then stop.

Comment: I checked by putting a log. The loop iterates very very slow. For just a console it is taking a second or even more per iteration. @NSjonas

Comment: So not really an infinite loop; just a really slow one. I've somehow managed to avoid writing LWC, so I can't offer much insight... Seems like there might be something else going on.

Comment: even the JSON.stringify line takes 5 to 6 mins. For array size of 600.

Comment: Is this "child component" on the page multiple times?

Comment: Yes it is, but I did try by including it only once. But still the same issue.

Comment: Might be you are updating that in `renderedCallback`, do you?

Comment: Running the chrome profiler might provide some insight: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/rendering-tools

Otherwise, I'd recommend creating a minimal reproducible example

Comment: No, I do not have a renderedCallback in my component. @rahulgawale

Comment: Do you have this array passed down through several layers? Could this be similar to [this performance issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/295924/array-find-and-array-findindex-has-worst-performance-in-lwc-lightning-locker)?

Comment: Probably this is the issue. I have it passing from my parent to grand child. Is this a bug in LWC and is there any direct workaround for this? @PhilW

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the assumption this is [this performance issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/295924/array-find-and-array-findindex-has-worst-performance-in-lwc-lightning-locker), this is effectively a bug in the LWC infrastructure. The workaround is to ensure each component accepts the array in an API property with a setter and ensure that you forcibly unproxy the data. Something like the following (this will copy all relevant properties from the options regardless of what they are called):

```
_options;

@api get options() {
    return this._options;
}

set options(value) {
    this._options = value.map(option => Object.assign({}, option));
}
```

The setter method explicitly removes any proxying by generating a new array with new objects in it that are the same structure as the inputs.

If you do this at the parent and child levels you should find the performance is improved.

Comment: Thanks @PhilW. I will try this solution.

Comment: This worked great! My component was timing out before, now it loads really fast