# LWC - Not able to handle big data iterations

Tags: lightning-web-components

as part of my job, I need to investigate the benefits of using LWC, as a javascript/node specialist, I was surprised when I saw that iterating a List retrieved from the apex is very slow.

I'm confused If I'm doing something wrong, or is it something wrong with LWC.

Here is my code

```
@api
get rows() {
    return this._rows;
}
set rows(value) {
    this._rows = value;
    if(value != null && value.length != 0) {
        this.test(value.length, false);
        this.test(value.length, true);
    }
    //console.time('render Rows');
    //this.renderRows(true, null, null, null, () => console.timeEnd('render Rows'));
}

test(len, proxy) {
    console.time('process Rows');
    let result = new Array(len);
    for(let i = len; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(proxy) {
            result[i] = Object.assign({ index : i }, this._rows[i]);
        }
        else result[i] = Object.assign({ index : i },{key1 : 'value 1', key2 : 'value 2', key3 : 'value 3', key4 : 'value 4', key5 : 'value 5'});
    }
    console.log(result);
    console.timeEnd('process Rows');
}
```

Rows are being set on the parent component as:

```
import getAllContacts from '@salesforce/apex/ContactUtils.getAll';
export default class TableDemo extends LightningElement {
    amount = 5;
    columns = columns;
    globalActions = globalActions;
    @wire(getAllContacts)
    contacts;
...
```

The results are an increase of 13seconds over 0.003seconds, its a critical difference...
[image]

Comment: To be clear, are you asking about LWC as it pertains to use in Salesforce, or LWC as it performs as a framework? There is a huge difference between the two.

Comment: as it pertains to use in Salesforce, it's a problem that I can only observe while handling Records provided by Apex.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by [PhilW](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/50252/phil-w) in the comments I changed the code from :

```
set rows(value) {
    this._rows = value;
    if(value != null && value.length != 0) {
        this.test(value.length, false);
        this.test(value.length, true);
    }
    //console.time('render Rows');
    //this.renderRows(true, null, null, null, () => console.timeEnd('render Rows'));
}
```

To

```
set rows(value) {
    console.time('process values');
    this._rows = value.map(cur => Object.assign({}, cur));
    console.timeEnd('process values');
    if(value != null && value.length != 0) {
        this.test(value.length, false);
        this.test(value.length, true);
    }
}
```

Improving a lot the performance, solving my problem

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't LWC specifically,  but rather Locker Service. It provides custom component security,  but this security comes at a cost. You should prefer to render a few hundred up to about one thousand rows, and use pagination or infinite scrolling. In addition,  lightning-datatable is a very heavy component, because it provides a lot of functionality. Rendering a custom table would improve performance considerably if you don't need all the bells and whistles of lightning-datatable.

Comment: Also note that LWC has poorly performing implementations of some standard JavaScript features (such as array iteration) when applied to proxy objects against proxy objects as covered [this Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/315544/loop-in-javascript-setter-takes-1-second-per-iteration/315559?r=SearchResults#315559).

Comment: Actually, I'm working on a datatable replacement with better performance than infinite scrolling, but with this loop cost its actually taking longer to load. This is because even if I don't show all the rows, when filtering and sorting I need to consider all records, not just the visible ones. Thats the problem

Comment: @PhilW Thank you, actually that change improved a lot the performance hit!

Comment: @PhilW Yep, that's locker service in play. If you write a OSS version, you'd actually see it run quite a bit faster; the ObservableMembrane is much lighter without Locker Service in play.