# Array.includes has worst performance in LWC lightning locker

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

#### Note: This question can be considered as extension of [Array.find and Array.findIndex has worst performance in LWC Lightning Locker](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/295924/70823) BUT it is not duplicate - check at the end of this question why there is no proper alternate work-around. It seems like all latest Array functions have worst performance in locker service.

According to [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.get_started_supported_javascript):

[image]

But basic functions like `Array.includes` (and find, findIndex, etc) from latest Ecmascript (*includes* is from ecma 2016) are failing in LWC locker.

Below is the example:

parent.html:

```html
<template>
    <div class="slds-theme_default slds-box">
        Parent
        <lightning-button label="test" onclick={test}></lightning-button>
        <c-child arr={arr}></c-child>
    </div>
</template>
```

parent.js

```js
export default class Parent extends LightningElement {
    @track arr = [];
    test() {
        this.arr.length = 0;
        for (let i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
            this.arr.push('a' + i);
        }
        console.log('Parent array ', this.arr.length);

        const t1 = new Date().getTime();
        const c1 = this.arr.includes('a422');
        const t2 = new Date().getTime();
        const c2 = this.arr.includes('a42222');

        const t3 = new Date().getTime();

        const c3 = this.arr.indexOf('a4222') > -1;
        const t4 = new Date().getTime();
        const c4 = this.arr.indexOf('a42222') > -1;
        const t5 = new Date().getTime();

        console.log(c1, c2, c3, c4);
        console.log('includes => ', t2 - t1, t3 - t2, t3 - t1);
        console.log('indexOf => ', t4 - t3, t5 - t4, t5 - t3);
    }
}
```

child.html:

```html
<template>
    Child
    <lightning-button label="test" onclick={test}></lightning-button>
</template>
```

child.js

```js
export default class Child extends LightningElement {
    @api arr;

    test() {
        console.log('child array ', this.arr.length);

        const t1 = new Date().getTime();
        const c1 = this.arr.includes('a422');
        const t2 = new Date().getTime();
        const c2 = this.arr.includes('a42222');

        const t3 = new Date().getTime();

        const c3 = this.arr.indexOf('a4222') > -1;
        const t4 = new Date().getTime();
        const c4 = this.arr.indexOf('a42222') > -1;
        const t5 = new Date().getTime();

        console.log(c1, c2, c3, c4);
        console.log('includes => ', t2 - t1, t3 - t2, t3 - t1);
        console.log('indexOf => ', t4 - t3, t5 - t4, t5 - t3);
    }
}
```

Below is the output:

[image]

## Although below is potential solution (as mentioned in [other](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/295924/70823) question),

child.js:

```js
    @api
    get arr() {
        return this._arr;
    }
    set arr(value) {
        this._arr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value));
    }
```

### But

This will remove the reactivity from `api valiable` **arr**. And we end up creating one more duplicate tracked variable which just keeps bloating the code as nested components increase and thereby increasing technical debt. So, we would need a proper solution such that LWC by itself handles these functions properly

Comment: Includes isn't really failing in this example, right? it's just slow performance?

Comment: slow like 400 times is like failing.. you go 1 level deep to grand-child, it will not finish and probably freeze your browser

Comment: You've already [asked this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/295924/2984). What additional insight to do hope to gain from another question? If anything, what should be done is opening a bug with Salesforce.

Comment: I'm going to ping some people over on social media. Stay tuned.

Comment: @sfdcfox just hoping some core LWC dev would give some pointers whether they have this on roadmap and so I mentioned as this question is extension of other question. Just surprizing that many functions are affected - never noticed *includes* before as dataset was small

Comment: I'd say it seems if an LWC is likely to receive an array via an API property you should make it use getter and setter methods and have the setter method explicitly create a new array using the content of the original. That way you remove proxy wrappers and avoid the exponential worsening of performance as you propagate the data down your LWC hierarchy.

Comment: @PhilW that would not exactly work as expected - added in question

Comment: @salesforce-sas as per your previous question and the comments around that, I 100% agree that this is a serious bug in the LWC infrastructure that Salesforce urgently needs to fix. Have you been able to raise a support case about it? I wonder if there is a known bug?