# Lightning Web Component - for:each is re-rendering entire list everytime it updates

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-renderer

I have a doubt about how LWC List rendering works, and see If I'm doing something wrong.
I'm doing an implementation of a virtual scroll in a table with multiple rows and columns, and I saw that if I push something to the list, Salesforce Framework will add the element at the end without updating, but If I remove the first then it will update every single element in the list resulting in sudden system slowness, which is not desired.
Is there a workaround or is Salesforce just not optimized for this?

Note: Please do not suggest pagination.

EDIT:
After Investigation and Discussion with Project Contributors its seems that this is Chrome Dev-Tools issue, https://github.com/salesforce/lwc/issues/2760

Answer (score 2):

Your performance will vary greatly depending on how you use your keys, and what component/technology you decide to use in particular. If you're in the habit of reindexing when you add/remove items, you're forcing the entire DOM to update when you modify the start. If you preserve your keys, you'll notice that the entire object is able to move with minimal DOM disturbance. I wrote a quick component [demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/xix4Wbwn4y8z7m02ZxLL/src/app.html?p=stories) for your that illustrates this, plus a [modified version](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/58mrATJKD6gJrV5b9ABQ/src/app.js?p=stories) using a `lightning-datatable` for comparison.

You'll notice that time increases slightly when using the left two buttons as you add items, but the speed increase will be minimal. If you use the `+ Start (Slow)` button, you'll quickly notice that `+ Start` will become much better (relatively) in performance as you approach tens of thousands of rows. The moral of the story is that you should not modify the key material or you'll suffer a 20-30%+ time penalty.

In general, avoid using a `lightning-datatable` with more than a few thousand items, as it is a very "heavy" component. If you write your own table/flexbox setup, you'll get a lot better performance (up to about 10x faster) if you're willing to sacrifice some flexibility in exchange.

Keep in mind that the DOM isn't great at reflecting changes quickly anyways (compared to canvas implementations), so a virtual scroll table (e.g. like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jpeter06/y9v2um2e/)) will have much better performance than physically rendering the entire thing at once. I call this out because there's a distinct difference between virtual tables that only render a few thousand elements max compared to rendering millions of actual cells. I guess you might technically call it pagination, except it's not apparent to the user that you are indeed faking it.

See also [this demo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/EEiNhkwKP/2/edit).

As a final note, note that Lightning Web Security will vastly improve your performance. Consider enabling this in Setup. You can read more [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/358101/2984).

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, thanks for the tips, that's actually exactly what I'm doing, but I'm seeing a bit of stutter on render when scrolling down. Here is a simple example that I've built [link](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/zm01qk8oaWr5sMvZfiDU), If you inspect the page you can see that when you click move down or enable scrolling and scroll down every row is refreshed even with the same key, if you move up/scroll up it works as expected. Since scrolling down it's the most frequent flow, its very problematic. The same does not happen with the fiddle in react...

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida Your rowHeight is too small a value. Doubling this to 34 seemed to solve the problem. [demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/H7fKMtQjCxnvNRDkYijL/src/app.js?p=stories). Just like any scroller of this nature, you need to make sure you leave enough buffer for the platform to react.

Comment: No it is still the same, my row height is for the expanded view, where the entry only occupies one line, resulting in a 'p' element with 17px height and making the calculation right. When shifting results the scroll works fine, but when pushing more results, the framework will not push the new results at the end and unshift the first elements, it will replace all the loop entries, in this demo the entry is only a paragraph, but a table has more render elements on it, meaning it is not optimized what so ever.

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida Can you post a short video or something of the behavior? I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be seeing.

Comment: Yes! [here](https://streamable.com/qpc8pr), there is no audio in the video, but I think it's easy to understand

Comment: As you can see when scrolling down, the framework replaces all the elements instead of pushing down the elements, so if I have a complex render in each row this will increase greatly the render time, instead of rendering 2 new rows, it renders every row again, depending on the height of the window

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same problem as me, I figured out a way where Salesforce Render runs faster, the solution is instead of slicing the visible rows is to do row transformation separately, so first add the new rows, set a timeout as 0 or promise to run the removal after, [here is a working example](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/zm01qk8oaWr5sMvZfiDU/src/app.css?p=stories). It is still not perfect but has a better performance for more complex row layouts. In the perfect world, Salesforce would optimize the engine

Comment: I see what you mean now. I would suggest posting an issue on GitHub (LWC is open source, after all). You might even try your hand at making a PR.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that for sure!